# dojo grid that is reloaded is not being updated in div

Tags: ajax, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a grid, that has a store, which gets json data from a url. When I m changing the values in the store, I am reassigning the store to the grid. I have observed in the developer Tools that the grid is being assigned the new store. Even when I check it with, dijit.byId(), I m able to see the updated store. But, the display still remains the same. Below is the code, I have used to reload my grid.

```
    function refreshGridWithNewStore() {
        require([
        "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
        "dojo/request",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ],
    function (DataGrid, Memory, ObjectStore, request) {
        request.get("DataPage.aspx", {
            handleAs: "json"
        }).then(function (data) {
            grid.store.close();
            dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectstore: new Memory({ data: data }) });
            grid.setStore(dataStore);                
            grid.render();
        });
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the property `objectstore` to `objectStore`. As far as I know it's case sensitive, so `objectstore` is not the same as `objectStore`. Even the `grid.render()` is not necessary I think.

So your code would become:

```js
dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: new Memory({ data: data }) });
```

I also made an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/GKw4V/).

If that doesn't work, try using the `startup()` function. Some widgets need to be completely rebuilt after changing the store and using something like the code below might help in your situation.

```js
grid.startup();
```

Comment: It was this typo, that was causing me problems. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, it's weird you didn't get any errors by the way. I copied your code and noticed there were problems while creating the `ObjectStore`.